# how to make link between buttons and pages in WPF windows application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

- i had look at that article
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750478%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
  but i couldn't get a practical way to do what i want.
- i wish i got a simple and direct way to do what i want
  [image]

Comment: You can refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750478(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Eve  i saw that link but i couldn't get a simple answer ...it explain many things and many conditions and at last i couldnt get a practical steps ... even it provides XAML codes and i don't know where i should write these codes in XAML part exactly

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Click` event handler for each button that you want to link to a page. In the handler, write the following code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("YourPageHere.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

I really think that you should try to follow the steps on that page one by one, though.